# How to see every Slackbot's recurring reminder?

Tags: slack

I want to see every active Slackbot's recurring reminder that has been set up on a channel by any user.

My goal is to actually import those to my calendar so I won't be surprised with a reminder of something that is starting right now.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process:

- Become a Slack admin or request help from your Slack admin
- Use the export tool to get access to the message history of each channel in JSON format
- Write a script to search through each JSON file of each channel
- Filter messages by at least the `bot message` subtype and the `Reminder` text

Here are the full list of subtypes for further filtering:

```
Type               Description
bot_message        A message was posted by an app or integration
me_message         A /me message was sent
message_changed    A message was changed
message_deleted    A message was deleted
channel_join       A member joined a channel
channel_leave      A member left a channel
channel_topic      A channel topic was updated
channel_purpose    A channel purpose was updated
channel_name       A channel was renamed
channel_archive    A channel was archived
Channel_unarchive  A channel was unarchived
group_join         A member joined a group
group_leave        A member left a group
group_topic        A group topic was updated
group_purpose      A group purpose was updated
group_name         A group was renamed
group_archive      A group was archived
group_unarchive    A group was unarchived
file_share         A file was shared into a channel
file_reply         A reply was added to a file
file_mention       A file was mentioned in a channel
pinned_item        An item was pinned in a channel
unpinned_item      An item was unpinned from a channel
```

**references**

- [Guide to Slack import and export tools – Slack Help Center](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/204897248-Guide-to-Slack-import-and-export-tools#toolsbyplan)
- [How to read Slack data exports – Slack Help Center](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/220556107-How-to-read-Slack-data-exports)